# What is the return type of Java built-in array's access operator when contains primitive type?

Tags: java, arrays, char, character, primitive

When array `xs` has primitive `char` values and someone try to accessing that value using `[]`, what is the return type?

Is it primitive `char` or wrapper `Character`?

I think it's always `Character` type, when array contains either `char` or `Character`.

Because when `char` minus `int`, the type of result is `char`.

```java
char x = 'A' - 1;
```

When `Character` minus `int`, the type of result is `int`.

```java
int x = new Character('A') - 1;
```

And result type of expression `xs[0] - 1` is always `int`.

```java
char[] xs = {'A'};
int x = xs[0] - 1;


char[] xs = {new Character('A')};
int x = xs[0] - 1;
```

Am I right? I cannot find document about result type and conversion of Java array's operator `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the return type of Java built-in array's access operator when contains primitive type?

It is the primitive type; e.g. for an `int[]` it is `int`, for a `char[]` it is `char` and so on.

---

However, I think you are getting yourself rather confused here.

All Java arithmetic operators applied to operands of type `byte`, `char`, `short` or `int` (or their wrapper types) always produce an `int` result.   So, the expression types of `'A' - 1` and `new Character('A') - 1` and `xs[0] - 1` are all `int`.

That is why you get an errors here:

```
 char a = 'A';
 char[] a2 = {'A'};
 char b = a + 1;                  // COMPILATION ERROR
 char c = a2[0] + 1;              // COMPILATION ERROR
 char d = new Character('A') + 1; // COMPILATION ERROR
```

You need type casts to make those assignments work.

So why **don't** you get a compilation error with the following one?

```
 char x = 'A' - 1;
```

In short, because `'A' - 1` is a (compile time) constant expression whose (`int`) value will fit into a `char` without any loss or information.

There is a special rule for the assignment operator that says:

- IF the LHS type is `byte`, `char` or `short`, AND
- IF the RHS expression type is `int`, AND
- IF the RHS expression is a compile time *constant expression*, AND
- IF the value of the RHS expression is in the range of the LHS type,
- THEN there is an implicit conversion from `int` to the LHS type.

The above is a simplification of the JLS rules ... which include a precise specification of what a *constant expression* is.

Intuitively, the compiler allows you to leave out the type cast because it "knows" that a type cast would not lose any information.

Answer (score 0):

> When array xs has primitive char values and someone try to accessing that value using [], what is the return type?

The type of the element always corresponds to the type of the reference (left hand side).  Auto-boxing occurs if primitives assigned on the right where the type is `Character[]` or auto-unboxing if references assigned where type is `char[]`

You could check using `instanceof Character` - it will return true to verify it's a `Character` or compile error if it's a primitive.

```
char[] xs = {'A'};
System.out.println(xs[0]); 
System.out.println(xs[0] instanceof Character);   // COMPILE ERROR: unexpected type  required: reference  found: char

char[] ys = {new Character('A')};
System.out.println(ys[0]); 
System.out.println(ys[0] instanceof Character);   // COMPILE ERROR: unexpected type  required: reference  found: char
     
Character[] cs = {'A'};   
System.out.println(cs[0] instanceof Character);   // true
```